# Inheritance: If private is default, why do these two examples not work the same way?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was working around with inheritance in C++. To my knowledge if you don't specify, B will always inherit private from A.

So why does this code work:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

int main(void)
{
    A b = B();
    return 0;
}
```

But this creates the "A is an inaccessible Base of B" error:

```
struct A {};
struct B : private A {};

int main(void)
{
    A b = B();
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect them to be the same?

Comment: As a side note, you're slicing your objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private inheritance is the default if the derived class is defined using the word `class`.

If you create it using `struct`, then inheritance is public by default.

Comment: Ah it's that simple! Thank you. Well my prof made a big mistake then!

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

> A class defined with the keyword `struct` has **public access** for its members and its base classes **by default**.

> A class defined with the keyword `class` has **private access** for its members and its base classes **by default**.

Or from [Derived Classes documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class)

> If access-specifier is omitted, it **defaults** to **public** for classes declared with class-key `struct` and to **private** for classes declared with class-key `class`.

The above quotes explain the behavior of your program.